# q library promises passing a value to done method

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm trying to find the purpose as well as how to use done method of the q library promises, if `done` can receive a value or function via `resolve` or `reject`, can someone explain how `done` method is called and how can pass any arguments to it?

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
.then(promisedStep2)
.then(promisedStep3)
.then(promisedStep4)
.then(function (value4) {
    // Do something with value4
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
})
.done();
```

Comment: Use `done` instead of `then`. Pass a value to it with `.resolve`.

Comment: @meagar what if I've then as well, and would like to pass some value to the done as well at the end? possible?

Comment: You have to invoke `.done` on a specific promise. Are you trying to invoke it on the *last* promise in the chain?

Comment: yes, last promise, as well as on failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In promises, whatever you resolve your deferred with, is the argument that get's passed to `done` or `then`. You can change the resolve value inside of a resolved handler by returning a different value. Like so

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
.then(promisedStep2)
.then(promisedStep3)
.then(promisedStep4)
.then(function (value4) {
  // Do something with value4
  return 'tada!';
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
})
.done(function(differentValue) {
  console.log(differentValue); // outputs "tada!"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual purpose of `.done` in Q is to handle errors so errors won't get suppressed.

If you have a rejected promise chain in Q, if you use `.then` all the way it becomes a silent failure, so the following code:

```
Q().then(function(){
    var val = JSON.prase(data);
    someEffectWith(val);
});
```

Is a silent failure, did you note the typo? Because there is never a way to know when the chain has ended it is crucial to use `.done` to let the library know:

```
Q().done(function(){
    var val = JSON.prase(data);
    someEffectWith(val);
});
```

Or:

```
Q().then(function(){
    var val = JSON.prase(data);
    someEffectWith(val);
}).done();
```

Will both echo a big red warning to your console, notifying you of the error. As for how it's called it has the exact same arguments of `.then` only it does not return a promise, instead it returns `undefined` so you know you can't chain to it (it terminated the chain).

It's worth mentioning some promise libraries, as well as native promises in firefox do this for you and you don't need to use `.done` in those libraries - the error will get logged regardless.